# Many clients and many servers in RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rpc

I read [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) and can you explain few things? 
For exaple I have run **rpc_server.py** in different tabs (3 tabs) of terminal.

**rpc_server.py** from that tutorial:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='rpc_queue')

def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def on_request(ch, method, props, body):
    n = int(body)

    print " [.] fib(%s)"  % (n,)
    response = fib(n)

    ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
                     routing_key=props.reply_to,
                     properties=pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id = \
                                                     props.correlation_id),
                     body=str(response))
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(on_request, queue='rpc_queue')

print " [x] Awaiting RPC requests"
channel.start_consuming()
```

Nice, I need to send in **send.py** 3 requests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika
import uuid

class FibonacciRpcClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
                host='localhost'))

        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        result = self.channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
        self.callback_queue = result.method.queue

        self.channel.basic_consume(self.on_response, no_ack=True,
                                   queue=self.callback_queue)

    def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        if self.corr_id == props.correlation_id:
            self.response = body

    def call(self, n):
        self.response = None
        self.corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                                   routing_key='rpc_queue',
                                   properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                         reply_to = self.callback_queue,
                                         correlation_id = self.corr_id,
                                         ),
                                   body=str(n))
        while self.response is None:
            self.connection.process_data_events()
        return int(self.response)

fibonacci_rpc = FibonacciRpcClient()

print " [x] Requesting fib(30)"
response = fibonacci_rpc.call(30)
print " [.] Got %r" % (response,)

fibonacci_rpc1 = FibonacciRpcClient()

print " [x] Requesting fib(30)"
response1 = fibonacci_rpc1.call(30)
print " [.] Got %r" % (response1,)

fibonacci_rpc2 = FibonacciRpcClient()

print " [x] Requesting fib(30)"
response2 = fibonacci_rpc2.call(30)
print " [.] Got %r" % (response2,)
```

Does it mean that script will waiting response from first request, then send second requests, wait again response, and then send third request?

I want to do 3 request in one moment, not to wait response and then send new request. How to do this?

How I need to change `send.py` or use another technique? Must I use threading or multiprocessing? Does RabbitMQ supports this?

Thanks!

Comment: I honestly can't understand what you are trying to do here. You seem to have got publishing and consuming in the same object, which completely defeats the purpose of queueing.

Comment: its for exaple. call(30), call(60), call(90)

Comment: That response seems to be completely irrelevant. The point of a queueing system is that you have (one or more) apps putting stuff on a queue, and a completely separate set of clients that subscribe to the queue and process the messages. Doing both actions in the same class and the same process is totally pointless.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you show an example, how it must be?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use threads if you want all three requests sent at once. A simple solution would look something like this:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

def make_rpc_call(value):
    fibonacci_rpc = FibonacciRpcClient()
    print " [x] Requesting fib({0})".format(value)
    response = fibonacci_rpc.call(value)
    print " [.] Got %r" % (response,)

for index in xrange(5):
    thread_ = threading.Thread(target=make_rpc_call, args=(30, ))
    thread_.start()
    sleep(0.1)
```

Keep in mind that Pika is not thread-safe, so you need to create one connection per thread. As an alternative you could look at my Flask example [here](https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py) for Pika. It is easy enough to modify to allow you to execute multiple requests asynchronously.

```
def rpc_call():
    # Fire of all three requests.
    corr_id1 = rpc_client.send_request('1')
    corr_id2 = rpc_client.send_request('2')
    corr_id3 = rpc_client.send_request('3')

    # Wait for the response on all three requests.
    while not rpc_client.queue[corr_id1] \
            or not rpc_client.queue[corr_id2] \
            or not rpc_client.queue[corr_id3]:
        sleep(0.1)

    # Print the result of all three requests.
    print rpc_client.queue[corr_id1]
    print rpc_client.queue[corr_id2]
    print rpc_client.queue[corr_id3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rpc_client = RpcClient('rpc_queue')
    sleep(1)
    print rpc_call()
```